# Getting '0' output instead of 51 cities by using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I was trying to Fetch all Uber Eats cities by using BeautifulSoup. I have tried with following codes and there was no error with running the code, But I have received '0' output instead of 51 cities. Can anyone please tell me how can I get expected output?

```
#Fetch all Uber Eats cities
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
  
URL = "https://www.ubereats.com/location"

req = Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/103.0.5060.114', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
# print(webpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser') 

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['city', 'state', 'url'])

#Fetching URL of all cities
states = soup.find_all("div", class_="av ax ay")
states = [state for state in states if state.text != "All Countries"]
len(states)

i = 0
for state in states:
    print(f"Processing: {state.text}")
    cities = state.parent.parent.findAll("a")
    for city in cities:
        df.loc[i] = [
            city.text,
            state.text,
            "https://www.ubereats.com" + city['href']
        ]
        i = i+1
```

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: when I open it in browser then I don't have `div` with class `av ax ay` - this page can use random names for classes and for every execution it can use different names. You should use different method to recognize `div` with city names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I open page in browser then I can't find `div` with class `av ax ay`. This page can use random names for classes and for every execution it can use different names. You should use different method to recognize div with city names.

For example for states

```
states = soup.select("h2 a")
```

and for cities

```
cities = state.parent.parent.parent.select("a span")
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
URL = "https://www.ubereats.com/location"

req = Request(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/103.0.5060.114', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
# print(webpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser') 

#Fetching URL of all cities
states = soup.select("h2 a")
states = [state for state in states if state.text != "All Countries"]
print('states:', len(states))

rows = []
for state in states:
    print("Processing:", state.text)
    cities = state.parent.parent.parent.select("a span")
    print('cities:', len(cities))
    for city in cities:
        rows.append([
            city.text,
            state.text,
            "https://www.ubereats.com" + city.parent['href']
        ])
        
# ---

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['city', 'state', 'url'])

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                city    state                                              url
0         Adamsville  Alabama      https://www.ubereats.com/city/adamsville-al
1          Alabaster  Alabama       https://www.ubereats.com/city/alabaster-al
2        Albertville  Alabama     https://www.ubereats.com/city/albertville-al
3     Alexander City  Alabama  https://www.ubereats.com/city/alexander-city-al
4         Alexandria  Alabama      https://www.ubereats.com/city/alexandria-al
...              ...      ...                                              ...
8664        Saratoga  Wyoming        https://www.ubereats.com/city/saratoga-wy
8665        Sheridan  Wyoming        https://www.ubereats.com/city/sheridan-wy
8666      Warren AFB  Wyoming      https://www.ubereats.com/city/warren-afb-wy
8667       Wheatland  Wyoming       https://www.ubereats.com/city/wheatland-wy
8668          Wilson  Wyoming          https://www.ubereats.com/city/wilson-wy

[8669 rows x 3 columns]
```